# Can I create ssl certificate chain from only SSLCertificateKeyFile.key and SSLCertificateFile.crt files?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I have website, where I doesn't installed ssl certificate.
In apache.conf I have only two files:

> SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainname.crt
>
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domainname.key

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html give me this error:

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
> install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
> certificate.

In docs I have see that I must have this files to create a certificate chain:

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- ComodoUTNSGCCA.crt
- EssentialSSLCA_2.crt
- domainname.crt
- UTNAddTrustSGCCA.crt

But in my /etc/ssl/ directory I have only domainname.crt file

Can I download other files from anywhere? Or I must buy new certificate with all files?

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded needle files from https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl_trust/tree/master/intermediate_ca
and It's work